# Temporal Coupling vs Unit of Work

Tags: c#, design-patterns

So, as has been [pointed out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148924/value-types-inferred-as-object-at-runtime-when-using-dynamic/16149405?noredirect=1#comment23075938_16149405) (and I entirely agree), [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) is a design smell, and generally comes in the form:

```
interface IDoSomething
{
    void Initialise();

    void DoSomethingThatOnlyWorksAfterInitialising();
}
```

In it's form above, there probably is something you can do about it (by means of constructor injection or maybe through an abstract factory, etc).

However, **how does this apply to a *Unit Of Work*?**

I'm currently in the joyous mess of my UoW's looking a little like

```
interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Initialise(); // sorts out connection sharing/opening/yada

    void Rollback();

    void Commit();
}
```

Admittedly, initialise still shouldn't be there.  I managed to convince myself otherwise by calling the method `Enlist` in my case.  Ignoring this though, **are** `Rollback` **and** `Commit` **considered under *temporal coupling*?**

---

### Further thoughts

Having pondered over this a little, isn't it either that the choice of wording ("temporal coupling") is wrong, or at least my interpretation of the wording?

In my mind, what the smell is trying to do is get coders to not rely upon some form of `Initialise` method, that can be counter-intuitive as is pointed out with the `EndpointAddressBuilder` framework example on the link above.

However, methods that effectively terminate further usage of the class are acceptable?  Methods like `Dispose` obviously have some form of *temporal coupling*; attempting to use the class after calling `Dispose` is going to cause you problems and you should know better.  Similarly with `Commit`, `Rollback`, and I suspect various other examples, in other cases.

Is it that the smell only relates to *initialisation coupling* (or some better choice of words that one of the bloggers can come up with?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Initialize` should return an object which can be rolled back or commited:

```
interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
     IUnitOfWork Create();
}

interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
    void Rollback(); // should get called by Dispose if Commit was never called.
}
```

Also, ideally your `IUnitOfWork` should extend `IDisposable`, and `Dispose` should be the same as `Rollback`.

Comment: _"Initialize should return an object which can be rolled back or commited:"_ - this just means use a factory.  I'm happy with that, it's in the OP.  However, adding `void Dispose` to my UoW interface, I would argue just compounds the problem; I then have 3 methods (Commit/Rollback/Dispose) that I believe fall under _temporal coupling_.  (For what it's worth, my UoW does implement IDisposable, was ommitted for brevity).  The question(s) remain, are Commit/Rollback a smell?  Is there a better way?  Or are there just exceptions to the _temporal coupling_ rules?

Comment: `Commit` and `Rollback` are temporally coupled to `Initialize` so just moving `Initialize` to a factory removes that problem.  If you are asking if they are temporally coupled to each other, or to the work actually being done, then yes they are.  But in this case the coupling is well known and desired and is the entire purpose of the interface.  Devs consuming the object _know_ that they must do their work, then afterwards call `Rollback` or `Commit`.  You could try doing it with a method that takes an Action and then either commits or rolls back depending on if the action threw an exception.

Comment: Might have been easier if I had ommitted "Initialise" from the OP.  Pretend it isn't there. :)  I don't think they are simply coupled to each other (i.e. Can't call `Rollback` after `Commit` and vice versa), but they potentially change state in such a way that any number of related/collborative/dependent classes and methods may no longer work *after* calling Commit/Rollback. This to me could be described by the term "temporal coupling", in that methods are coupled to the sequence (time) in which they are called.  Just trying to work out where my understanding is wrong I guess.

Comment: yes I agree with you.  They are temporally coupled to whatever systems they are controlling.  But I believe, as you state, this is an acceptable exception use of temporal coupling since the coupling is intentional and there isn't really a way to provide transactional behavior without it.  The key is to ensure the code which is consuming the `IUnitOfWork` does not have access to these other classes/systems which are made invalid by calling `Commit/Rollback` so the relevant code cannot get itself into trouble.  If you are following other good design practices then this should be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Use an `abstract` base and the Template Pattern**

In general, if the proper execution order is a concern implement that order in an `abstract` class. As for the`IUnitofWork` methods make them `virtual` or `abstract` (as appropriate) and write a method that fixes the call order (thus, the template) - and you don't make the base class "implement" the interface. Further the `abstract` base can declare implementation of whatever interface then defer implementation or provide default implementation.